# Dynamic method binding with inheritance in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I am new to python (~ a month), and I wish I had switched to it sooner (after years of perl).

**Problem**:  I want objects to have different functionality to the same method call based on their type. The methods are assigned at runtime, based on the module loaded (which composes all objects).

**Question**: I wanted to know if there was a popular design pattern that I could use instead of the below, or if this already has a design pattern name (I sadly have no formal CS background, and knowing this will help my documentation)**?**

I have a class hierarchy (as of now, 26 of them with 3 base classes). Only the base classes have some trivial methods (eg: add_child), and each derived class only extends the base class with new data attributes (specific to the derived class), overriding methods when necessary (eg: __str__).

I am dealing with tree(s) where nodes are of different classes. Yet, the nodes should the same certain method names (`stringify`, `print_tree`, `emit`, `eval`, `transform_X`, etc), thereby allowing easy/blind iterator operation. Each method may do something different, yet the methods have the same call name (like *polymorphism*).

I primarily wanted to grant specific abilities (methods) to nodes, based on their type. Initially, I implemented this using the [Visitor Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891637/visitor-pattern-in-python?newreg=d5c745988c5844e8a248268074a9b7bb). But, then realized I didn't really have to, considering I was working in Python.

In the below example, I have methods which are dynamically assigned to classes. Note, in below example the iteration/recursion method call name (`print_tree`) is different from the function name (`generic__print_tree`).

```py
#astmethods.py
def generic__print_tree(self, level=1):
    """
    Desc: print nodes with indentation
    Target: Any tree node
    """
    print("{}> {}".format('-' * level, self))
    for child in self.children:
            child.print_tree((level + 1))


def ASTNode__stringify(self):
    """
    Desc: Return string representation of the tree under this node
    Target: AST/CFG nodes
    """
    text = str(self)
    for child in self.children:
            text += ", { " + child.stringify() + " }"
    return text
```

Finally the **main** modules has this function, *extend_types()* which gets called during module init. The nodes are expected to do different things, within the context of this module, based on their type (not value). The methods assigned are inherited, unless overridden.

```py
# mainModule1.py
def extend_types():
    """
    Upgrade the AST node classes with neat functions for use within this module's context
    """
    # same simple functions across class hierarchies
    # I should just derive them both from a common base class to avoid this
    ASTNode.print_tree = generic__print_tree
    SimpleNode.print_tree = generic__print_tree

    # ASTNode and all derived class get this method
    ASTNode.stringify = ASTNode__stringify

    # All AST nodes get the base method, except for Ignore and Arraysel type nodes
    # traversal looks the same with child.tidy()
    ASTNode.tidy = ASTNode__tidy
    ASTIgnore.tidy = ASTIgnore__tidy
    ASTArraySel.tidy = ASTArraySel__tidy

    # All AST nodes get the base method, except for the Coverage and If type nodes
    ASTNode.transform_controlFlow = ASTNode__transform_controlFlow
    ASTCoverage.transform_controlFlow = ASTCoverage__transform_controlFlow
    ASTIf.transform_controlFlow = ASTIf__transform_controlFlow
```

edit: removed distracting info, made the example for a single module context

Comment: There is no question here. However, I can comment that the idea of `extend_types()` would work under controlled conditions, but it is a very ugly idea. If I ever saw that in "serious" code, I would remove it.

Comment: I have highlighted the question (it was in the first para).

Upon removal, what can grant me similar functionality? Visitor pattern, yes. But, that would add a layer of call just to resolve to the correct method. And I'd need to decide whether the composite traversal would need to be in the VisitorFunction class or have different types of traversal methods in the base class itself.

Or...back to replicating these methods in base classes (at different levels in the hierarchy).

Answer (score 0):

### Problem Summary

Ignoring the irrelevant details, the problems here can be summed up as follows:

There is one base class and many derived classes. There is a certain functionality which should apply to all of the derived classes, but depends on some external switch (in the question: choice of *"**main** module"*).

The idea in the question is to monkeypatch the base class depending on the switch.

### Solution

Instead of that, the functionality which depends on the external switch should be separated.

In example:

```
# There is a base class:

class ASTNode(object):
    pass


# There are many derived classes, e.g.:


class ASTVar(ASTNode):
    pass


# One implementation of function stringify or another
# should be defined for all objects, depending on some external factor


def stringify1(node):
    # something


def stringify2(node):
    # something else


# Depending on whatever, choose one of them:

stringify = stringify1
```

This is now used just a little bit differently than in the original code: intead of `node.stringify()`, there is now `stringify(node)`. But there is nothing wrong with that.

BTW...

Maybe it would be more pleasing to the eye to use a class:

class NodeHandler1(object):
    def print_tree(node):
        # do something

```
def stringify(node):
    # do something

...
```

But that is not required at all.

### The Moral

Do not monkeypatch. That is always bad design.

Comment: I might not have fully comprehended your solution, but could you explain how would this allow classes to have have different `stringify` functionality. Would the external switch specific `stringify1`/`stringify2` have an if/else ladder to pick class specific tweaks (decided by class name)? In that case, there would be only one `stringify` function per module (maybe even a pleasing function container like `NodeHandler` per module) which would take any node class as an argument, and work with it/traverse accordingly. Did I read that right?

Comment: If the choice of `stringify1` vs `stringify2` is depending on some factor outside of this class inheritance tree, then it does not belong here. In other words, `stringify` is not a method of node at all. You should not look for a solution limited to decision that `ASTNode.stringify` method exists, because that is not optimal.

Comment: But, isn't that what the Visitor Pattern does? It allows classes to act like they have been granted new methods. The method it would call would depend on the type, there avoiding the if/else ladder in the method. I not only have a different `stringify` per _external switch_, but have different ones for different node types within that _external switch_. For example, `self.stringify()` (and traverse) should invoke `SomeDerivedNode_stringify1`, if it was of type `DerivedClass_stringify1`, else it would invoke `BaseClass_stringify1`.

Comment: The visitor pattern is overly complicated (like many other textbook design patterns) because it was designed for other languaegs, not python. On the other hand, what you did is just wrong. I was trying to give you an elegant solution, but I don't really know what you are trying to do. You should not blindly follow design patterns, because there are often better solutions. Here, you could have an `isinstance` in `stringify` (simple, but still rather ugly) or you could split the logic which depends only on node type from logic which depends on the other switch. Then combine those.

Comment: `isinstance` would imply an if/else ladder checking the type within `stringify` (which I want to avoid?). I have edited the question details (and stripped all junk) to really zone in on what I had to say. Could you please have a look at it again? Yes, it is still _monkeypatching_. Assume I only have one module (no more external switches), but I want the nodes to have different functionality to the same call based on their type, within the same local context.